# Correct usage of sum sign

Tags: summation

I want to express in a formula that variables with a certain property shall be added. I think it is best expressed by an example.

$A$ is a superset of $B$ and $C$.

$B$ can have the properties $X$ and $Y$.

$C$ also can have the properties $X$ and $Y$.

I want to sum up all $B$'s and $C$'s with the property $X$.

Is it correct to write

$$ \sum_{x\in A}( B_x + C_x ) ?$$

Comment: What do you mean by $B_x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that notation does not do what it sounds like you want. If I understand you correctly, you mean

> $A$ is a superset of both $B$ and $C$.
>
> An element of $B$ may or may not have the property $X$.
>
> An element of $C$ may or may not have the property $X$.
>
> You want to sum all the elements of $B$ and $C$ that have the property $X$.

I would write something like

$$ \sum_{s\in B\cup C, X(s)} s $$

or

$$ \sum_{s\in (B\cup C)\cap X} s $$

depending on how you prefer to write down "has the property X" symbolically.